# Load pdo_firebird.dll

Tags: php, windows, apache, pdo, firebird

I want to run PHP extension, to be able connect to firebird database. In php.ini there is enabled line extension=pdo_firebird.dll, and the file exists where are other extensions - in /ext directory. Every time I restart Apache (and PHP), I can't see extension loaded in phpinfo(). Why?
I'm running Apache 2.2 on Windows 8 with PHP 5.4.

Comment: Have you verified that the .dll extension is present?

Comment: Yes, it's present. DLL is default in package from php.net

Answer (score 1):

You have to install fbclient 2.5.x also please enable php error reporting in php.ini

display_startup_errors so you can see the actual loading error for pdo_firebird.dll

Comment: Please check the logs and update the question , also you need to match the x32/x64 platform match : Firebird x64 , Apache x64 ... (If you use x64)

Comment: Every is correct. I've read php documentation abut installation of PDO Firebird. And there I can see that I should run configuration command with `--with-pdo-firebird` parameter, and when I run `phpinfo()`, I can't see it in configure command. Is it the reason of my problem? Where can I correct it?

Answer (score 1):

Copy fbclient.dll and gds32.dll to apache/bin/ directory and restart apache. This work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I managed to solve following these steps:

Step 1 - Make sure your Firebird is installed correctly, I'm using Firebird 2.5.2

Step 2 - Go to the folder where php is. In my case it is:  `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10\`

Step 3 - Open the `php.ini` file and uncomment the following lines:

Example before commenting:

`;extension = php_interbase.dll`

`;extension = php_pdo_firebird.dll`

Example after uncommenting the lines:

`extension = php_interbase.dll`

`extension = php_pdo_firebird.dll`

Save, close the file, and restart apache.

If it does not work, seize the next steps:

Copy the following dll's `(fbclient.dll and gds32.dll)` to the bin folder in apache:
`C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\bin`

If you do not have these dll's, you can go to the Firebird installation folder and get it from there. In my case the complete path is this:
`C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_5\bin\fbclient.dll`

If you do not see this directory, you can download them through the links:

- https://www.azdll.net/files/fbclient-dll.html
- https://www.azdll.net/files/gds32-dll.html

Then just copy to the directory mentioned above and then restart apache.

I recommend using a manager because it makes a lot easier and solves some problems. I use Wampserver - version 3.0.6 - 64bit here

For min work

Comment: for firebird it is not necessary php_interbase.dll, php_pdo_firebird.dll quite enough

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything without success with Firebird 4.0

Finally I replaced Firebird 4.0 with Firebird 3.0 and it worked

(using the same php.ini configuration with "extension = php_pdo_firebird.dll")

During the installation process I checked "*copy the Firebird client library in the system folder*".

This might have been the thing.